# What is the type of custom class and how to assign its type to an function's argument in python

Tags: python, class, types

Question : In the below code snippet I want to assign the type to source_sol and target_sol args in the function move. What type should I assign it to be ?

```
class Solution:
    def __init__(self):
        self.hamming_loss = 0
        self.active_features = []
        self.rank = None
        self.pareto_solution = True

    def move(self, source_sol, target_sol) -> None:
        return None

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return None

source_sol = Solution()
target_sol = Soltuion()
new_sol = Solution()
new_sol.move(source_sol, target_sol)
```

Comment: Note: you appear to have a typo: `target_sol = Soltuion()` is doubtless meant to be `target_sol = Solution()`

Comment: Do you mean "annotate"? Like `def move(self, source: Solution, target: Solution) -> None:` which will require a `from __future__ import annotations`.

Comment: Maybe, one point to improve your quality of questions in future: make the example you give minimal (why this longish `__init__`  and the `__str__` w/o relevance for the question?).

Comment: *classes are types in Python*